# How to configure GCC for OpenMP 4.5 offloading to Nvidia PTX GPGPUs

Tags: gcc, openmp, nvidia, ptx, offloading

With gcc 7.1 released, we can now configure gcc for openmp 4.5, offloading to Nvidia PTX GPGPUs. That's what they say in the release note (approximately).

So my question is, is there any special flags to activate this configuration when compiling openmp 4.5 to target nvidia devices?

Comment: Some instruction is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29297814/3953764)

Comment: `g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none -fno-stack-protector` works for me with Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

I  found sth from there wiki but i didn't test it yet. putting  it just in case
for someone in need.

`-foffload=nvptx-none`